# Class admin does not exist Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to redirect to the file I need, it displays an error that the Admin class does not exist, how to fix it?

```
  Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::user()->role == 'Admin')
        return redirect('admin');
    elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'User')
        return redirect('user');
    else
        return redirect('error');
});
Route::get('error', function () {
    return "Sorry, you are unauthorized to access this page.";
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::view('/', 'role.admin');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'user'], function () {
    Route::view('/', 'role.user');
   });
  });
```

Comment: Do you have the admin middleware???

Answer (score 1):

After creating middleware you need to register it in `app/http/Kernel.php` file in `protected $routeMiddleware` array. Then you can use this middleware in your routes(`web.php/api.php`):

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
];
```